# How to get distinct value from repeating result

Tags: mysql

I have a table like name 'items'

```
id      sender  receiver        item
1       1       2               computer
2       2       1               mobile
3       1       3               ipad
4       4       1               ring
5       3       1               camera
6       1       8               pc
7       5       1               ring
8       1       10              tablet
```

I only can do these two queries like

```
SELECT `receiver` FROM `items` WHERE `sender` ='1'
```

result

```
2
3
4
10
```

and

```
SELECT `sender` FROM `items` WHERE `receiver` ='1'
```

result

```
2
4
3
5
```

How can I get distinct recevier/sender(count only one, if comes more than 1) where sender/receiver=1

like bellow

```
2
3
4
5
10
```

Comment: If I want to get the order of sender/receiver with whom last interaction was happened where sender/receiver=1, I mean the order (10, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2). Sorry Brother, for asking one more, actually it seems better ordering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT receiver FROM items WHERE sender ='1'
UNION
SELECT sender FROM items WHERE receiver ='1'
```

Depending on your results, you may need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` with each query.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03c1fb/1)

(Produces slightly different results given your sample data, as I think you had some typos)

Comment: Thanks, I was checking your answer and clarified for me that UNION clause is the shortcut of UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: I would prefer this solution, because, if you designed your table thoughtfully, you, probably have indexes for "receiver" and "sender" fields, and this select would USE them both.

Comment: @sgeddes, Bro 1 more question, is that possible to order by id, so that I can get latest one first !!!

Comment: @AbuBakkarSiddique -- of course, just add an `order by` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03c1fb/4

Comment: @sgeddes, Brother, If I want to get the order of sender/receiver with whom last interaction was happened where sender/receiver=1, I mean the order (10, 5, 8, 3, 4, 2). Sorry Brother, for asking one more, actually it seems better ordering...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this *without* `union`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (case when receiver = 1 then sender else receiver end) 
FROM items
WHERE sender = 1 or receiver = 1
```

Comment: I prefer this solution!

Comment: I would not prefer it, because, if you designed your table thoughtfully, you, probably have indexes for "receiver" and "sender" fields, and this select would ignore them for sure.

Comment: Under most reasonable circumstances (but not all), sgeddes answer is more efficient with indexes on `sender` and `receiver`.  This is just an alternative, that might even be the better performing solution under some circumstances.